# Duplicate footnotes when tabulary is inside minipage

Tags: tables, footnotes, minipage, tabulary

I want to make table footnotes by nesting a tabular or tabulary inside a minipage, and that inside a table. When I do this with tabular, it works exactly as it should. But with tabulary, it produces two sets of footnotes at the bottom, and the footnote numbers in the main text are those of the duplicate footnotes.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabulary,lipsum}

\begin{document}

Why are footnotes duplicated when a tabulary is placed inside a minipage?
It happens in memoir class and the standard \LaTeX classes.

See table~\ref{table:mwe} for an example.

\begin{table}
\caption{Tabulary inside minipage with footnotes}
\label{table:mwe}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{lL}
Lipsum para. 1%
    \footnote{This is the first footnote.}
                & \lipsum[1]\\
Lipsum para. 2%
    \footnote{This is the second footnote.}
                & \lipsum[2]\\
\end{tabulary}

\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

I would prefer a solution that allows me to keep using tabulary, as I have used this technique throughout a 400-page dissertation. I am using the memoir class, but it also happens in the standard LaTeX classes.

[This question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119571/counter-problem-with-tabulary) seems to stem from the same problem.

Comment: This behaviour is really strange. I tried the `footmisc` package, but it did not correct it.

Comment: @Clément the behaviour's only strange if you don't expect it:-) tabulary sets its content twice so everything happens twice except those things that are protected against that.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle : I must admit that I do not know `tabulary`, so it *is* a strange world to me!

Comment: @Clément you would see same in `\caption` or AMS alignments or any other construct that typesets the content multiple times while experimenting with the layout.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just make the footnote on the final typesetting run, not while tabulary is measuring things.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{tabulary,lipsum}

\begin{document}

Why are footnotes duplicated when a tabulary is placed inside a minipage?
It happens in memoir class and the standard \LaTeX classes.

See table~\ref{table:mwe} for an example.

\begin{table}
\caption{Tabulary inside minipage with footnotes}
\label{table:mwe}

\begin{minipage}{\textwidth}

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{lL}
Lipsum para. 1%
    \ifx\[$\else\footnote{This is the first footnote.}\fi
                & \lipsum[1]\\
Lipsum para. 2%
    \ifx\[$\else\footnote{This is the second footnote.}\fi
                & \lipsum[2]\\
\end{tabulary}

\end{minipage}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: So could I do this, then? \newcommand{\floatfootnote}[1]{\ifx\[$\else\footnote{#1}\fi} . But can you explain more what your solution does?

Comment: tabulary sets the content twice the first time it makes lots of local definitions so that constructs are "safe" to be measured, one of them is that it makes display math constructs into inline math (so they may be measured) that's irrelevant except that it makes `\ifx\[$ an easy test for the first or second pass of tabulary, on the first pass it os true, so do nothing \else on the second path `\[` has its normal meaning, so make the footnnote.

Comment: Fixed a typo in my macro and I can replace this easily throughout--thanks. `\newcommand{\floatfootnote}[1]{\ifx\[$\else\footnote{#1}\fi}`