# Cornell style layout

Tags: layout

I am looking for a way to add text to the left "column" in my notes template. (It isn't actually a separate column in the code - it just looks that way on paper.) [Here is an example of what a full set of notes looks like](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1gJYWYpSQRYFJmtbFwRixGfgUUu5Xh4we). I've considered using minipage but then I lose the ability to use \vfill, which is my go-to for spacing out problems, and my notes span multiple pages.

Here is a MWE of my template:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0.85in, right=0.85in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.95in]{geometry}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lastpage, epstopdf}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{background}

%=======HEADER & FOOTER=======%
\def\lesson{Lesson Title}
\def\outcome{\textbf{Learning Outcomes:} Outcomes go here. }

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.4pt}
\lfoot{My Name $\diamond$ \the\year}
\cfoot{Page \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\rfoot{\lesson}

%=======CORNELL STYLE FORMAT=======%
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgContents{\rule{1pt}{0.855\paperheight}}
\SetBgHshift{-1.6in}
\SetBgVshift{-0.1in}

%=======CUSTOM BOXES=======%
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{colbacktitle=gray!15!white, colback=white, coltitle=black, title={#2},fonttitle=\bfseries,#1}

\parindent 0ex

%=======BODY=======%
\begin{document}
\section*{\lesson \hfill Date: \hrulefill}
\begin{tcolorbox}{\outcome}\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{adjustwidth}{2in}{} 

Notes go here.

\vfill
\begin{mybox}{Critical Thinking:}Question goes here.\end{mybox}

\end{adjustwidth}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Any advice would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Now I have not time  even to read the question but maybe [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/188601/11604) help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that I'm not using relative distances but I think that this one reproduces what you want. I use `minipage` because it gives you more control on what you're writing, but I'll try to use `adjustwidth` and put a solution here if I can get it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[left=0.85in, right=0.85in, top=0.5in, bottom=0.95in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{changepage}
\usepackage{lastpage, epstopdf}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{background}

%=======HEADER & FOOTER=======%
\def\lesson{Lesson Title}
\def\outcome{\textbf{Learning Outcomes:} Outcomes go here. }

\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{1.4pt}
\lfoot{My Name $\diamond$ \the\year}
\cfoot{Page \thepage/\pageref{LastPage}}
\rfoot{\lesson}

%=======CORNELL STYLE FORMAT=======%
\SetBgScale{1}
\SetBgAngle{0}
\SetBgColor{black}
\SetBgContents{\rule{1pt}{0.855\paperheight}}
\SetBgHshift{-1.6in}
\SetBgVshift{-0.1in}

%=======CUSTOM BOXES=======%
\newtcolorbox{mybox}[2][]{colbacktitle=gray!15!white, colback=white, coltitle=black, title={#2},fonttitle=\bfseries,#1}

\parindent 0ex

%=======BODY=======%
\begin{document}
\section*{\lesson \hfill Date: \hrulefill}
\begin{tcolorbox}{\outcome}\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{minipage}[t][.91\textheight]{1.6in}
 More notes go here.
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][.91\textheight]{.4in}
\hphantom{m}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}[t][.91\textheight]{4.8in}
 Notes go here.
\null\vfill%
\begin{mybox}{Critical Thinking:}Question goes here.\end{mybox}

\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

The problem with `minipage` and `\vfill` is treated in this post: [Why does \vfill not work inside minipage?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/135361/why-does-vfill-not-work-inside-minipage). I hope I've helped!

Comment: I could make this work. The only issue here is that if the content is too long to fit on a page, it does not get pushed down to the next page. Would I just use manual pagebreaks and create a new set of minipages on each subsequent page? And thank you for the \vfill solution!

Comment: Of course you can! Trying to use `changepage` package with the `adjustwidth` command it won't work as you desire. Maybe you can see what was answered in this post https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/120688/how-to-have-two-adjustwidth-environments-starting-at-the-same-height