# How to Remove `\marginparwidth` for Pages without Margin Notes?

Tags: line-breaking, margins, marginnote, sidenotes, layout

In regular LaTeX, how could I remove the space reserved for sidenotes on pages that don't have any margin notes?

Issue: Just trying to use the extra space if possible.

I am trying to do this with either `\marginnote` or `\marginpar`.

Although I would prefer to have the sidenotes 'inset', right now I am just trying to do it the traditional way.  The "inset" approach I have tried uses another question's[`\wrapfig`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120589/153289) approach, but "weirdness" happens when notes are close to the bottom of the page, which seems to be a known/accepted issue.

Comment: it would be possible in luatex (and with a lot of lua to re-implement the linebreaking rules) but normally this isn't possible: tex breaks the paragraph in to lines before considering page breaking, so you can not change the line width at a page break.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would be possible in luatex (and with a lot of lua to re-implement the linebreaking rules) but normally this isn't possible: tex breaks the paragraph in to lines before considering page breaking, so you can not change the line width at a page break.

Comment: I took out the references to Lua in my question.  That way, someone else can post that question without it being a duplicate.  Thanks again.